# How to display picker view in MM-dd-yy format in iOS 5.1?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4

In my application i am using pickerview

My problem is that when in iOS 4.3 Picker view comes MM-dd-yy format,

[image]

in iOS 5.1 Picker view comes dd-MM-yy format,

[image]

**I want MM-dd-yy format in iOS 5.1**

My code is below,

I created picker view programmatically with this code,

```
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 325, 300)];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
datePicker.date = [NSDate date];

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];        
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy"];
NSString *dateString = [df stringFromDate:today];
dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
```

Anybody suggest me how can i resolve this issue on iOS 5.1?

Comment: no i m also using iOS 5.1, and also use your code in my application  Picker view comes MM-dd-yy format :)

Comment: I upvoted your question as it is good

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My all code works is fine,

Problem is with Settings,

My region format is set to india and change it to United state,

All works fine.....

Comment: Does it change to very first time when run the app?

Comment: Programmatically is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Your question is good but if you bring the solution through coding it will be amazing.

Comment: you can change the datepicker locale instead of changing the device region.

Answer (score 5):

Check this

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 325, 300)];

 datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

 datePicker.date = [NSDate date];

 [datePicker addTarget:self   action:@selector(LabelChange:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

 [self.view addSubview:datePicker];

 [datePicker release];
```

Answer (score 4):

For this you can make your custom picker.

Or you want to format the date then use this code..

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy"];
NSString *date = [dateFormat stringFromDate:datePicker.date];    
NSLog(@"date is >>> , %@",date);
```

Answer (score 4):

Change region to United states i.e locale settings

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"US"];
        [datePicker setLocale:locale];
```

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 5.1 display `UIDatePicker` as it is in 4.3

**Your and mine both of code is same but in my application UIDatePicker display

with *MM-dd-yyyy***

Use it ...may be helpful for you.

```
   self.DatePicker= [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)];
    self.DatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [self.DatePicker addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(SetDatePickerTime:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.asheet addSubview:self.DatePicker];
```