# Change iOS Datepicker Display Format

Tags: ios, datepicker

How can I change the `iOS` `Datepicker` date selected display format? The format displays as 2015-12-30. I want the date to display as 12/30/2015.
[image: example]

Comment: You can find the answer in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740423/how-to-display-picker-view-in-mm-dd-yy-format-in-ios-5-1

Comment: @CongTran I am looking to change how the date is displayed once you select a date

Comment: You mean when you click done button on `UIDatePicker`,then show the value on `UILabel` in MM/dd/yyyy format?

Comment: @CongTran yes. I have a web based app created with Phone gap. I make edits to the app using xcode.

Comment: I don't know how to do it in Phonegap, but I can show you in objective-C or Swift if you want.

Comment: sure sounds great anything will help @CongTran

Comment: @HiteshBoricha where would I place this? I have a .php file that will allow me to change the date format but I do not know the iOS datepicker month, day, year property names.

Comment: @CongTran i am using php files for my website and the app. on the website php file i use $stdate=$stdatemm."/".$stdatedd."/".$stdateyy;
$endate=$endatemm."/".$endatedd."/".$endateyy; to control the date display format because i know the property names for month, date, year. In the iOS app i use $stdate=$mm."/".$dd."/".$yyyy;
$endate=$mm."/".$dd."/".$yyyy; and the date displays as // because i do not know the Ios Date picker Month, date, year property names.

Comment: sorry man, I'm not familiar with php :(, i'm trying to search the answer

Comment: @CongTran Thanks. I am researching too. I found the entire date property name but not the individual month, date, year.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, as I told you in comment above. Here is how you can get the date in string from `UIDatePicker`

in `Objective-C`

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:self.yourDatePicker.date];
```

in `Swift`

```
let dateFormater: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormater.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
let stringFromDate: String = dateFormater.stringFromDate(self.yourDatePicker.date) as String
```

Answer (score 1):

I have set up my datePicker in Storyboard. In Swift 5, in order to get dates in correct format, you should do the following:

1. Specify datePicker's locale in Storyboard (that would translate months' names to your language).
2. Create dateFormatter like @Cong Tran wrote. Though now you could use DateFormatter instead of NSDateFormatter.
3. Convert string back to date using date(from:) method using optional binding.
4. Assign formatted date to datePicker's date.