# How to set custom date display on UIDatePicker?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uidatepicker

I have added a UIDatePicker from storyboard. By default picker shows me the date format as (October - 26 - 2017). But i want the format to be dispayed as (26 - 10 - 2017 ).I am not able to display date in this format on UIDatePicker.Please tell me how can i do this?

[image]

Comment: Did you read the reference guide?

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740423/how-to-display-picker-view-in-mm-dd-yy-format-in-ios-5-1

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a suggestion what to do with your issue. 1) UIDatePicker have two properties: `datePickerMode` of kind `UIDatePickerMode`. In your case, you need to set this property to `UIDatePickerModeDate`; and 2) `locale` of kind `NSLocale`. For best user experience, use locale familiar to the user. Do not force user, using date formats, not applicable to his locale.

Comment: But it the requirement of project.Designer has designed this way and i have to implement like this only

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this.

From Apple's documentation for: UIKit > Views and Controls > UIDatePicker

> **Appearance**
>
> > The appearance of UIDatePicker is not customizable.

The only thing Apple allows you to change is the date picker *mode*, which is not what you want. To change the layout to "dd-mm-yyyy", you will need build your own customized picker.

The way I'd suggest going about this, is instead of using UiDatePicker, to use UIPicker. Then, create and assign to that picker a unique class, which inherits from UIPickerView. This way you can customize it exactly how you want. Here is a helpful link for how to get all dates between a range (which is how UIDatePicker() is populated) - [Swift: Print all dates between two NSDate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536612/swift-print-all-dates-between-two-nsdate)